# SQL Server displaying historical data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005. I have a table called Product. Now I need to find out the price of a product in a given month. Whatever is the price of the product at the end of the month is actually the price. To make the scenario more clear I have the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(ProductID int, Product Varchar(50), Price Decimal(5,2), FromDate DateTime, ToDate Datetime);
```

Data may looks like as following:

```
INSERT INTO Product(ProductID, Product, Price, FromDate, ToDate)
SELECT 1,Pen,2.99,'01/15/2011','03/25/2011'
UNION
SELECT 2,Pen,3.99,'03/25/2011','05/02/2011'
UNION
SELECT 3,Pen,4.99,'05/02/2011',NULL
```

Now here, the current price of Pen is 4.99 because its ToDate is still Null. Now price of Pen is 2.99 in Month January and February. The price of Pen is changed to 3.99 in March 25, so the price of the Pen in March is 3.99. The price of pen is again changed in May to 4.99. So the price of pen in May and forward is May.

Now, I need to write a sql script that will give me the price of the product for the given month. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2167/get-current-price

Comment: No Fromdate would never be NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT * From Product where @monthenddate 
between FROMDATE and isNUll(TODate,get date())
```

I'll leave it to you to calculate month end date

Comment: The one problem with this is that if you put in '05/02/2011' as @monthenddate you get two results. Which is fine as long as either your inputs can be guaranteed to be not be on the endpoints of the ranges or if you can fix the data so there's no overlap

Comment: true, but the request was to get price for a given month, and month was assume to be the last day of the month.   Theoretically, you would never enter 5/2/2011 based on what he asked for...

Comment: As I said it requires that the inputs be guaranteed. I get nervous whenever I make that a requirement. So usually I just ignore the day part of the input extracting the month and year out, or fixing the endpoints of then range by adding or substracting a day.  e.g. `between FROMDATE and DateAdd(d,isNUll(TODate,get date()) -1)` then I don't have to worry.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, but you should note that if the input is 5/02/2011 then the price will be 4.99. If you want it to be 3.99 just change the comparison opperators to be < and >=

```
Select price  
From
          Product
 Where
          Product = 'Pen'
          And fromdate <= @inputDate
      And (todate > @inputDate or todate is null)
```

See it at [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2168/sample-for-8286274)

Comment: I don't think this will work. Because let's say I pass the value '04/01/2011' as @inputDate to determine the price of pen in the month of April 2011. Now your script will return the value 4.99 which is not correct. The price of pen in April 2011 is 3.99.

Comment: @mrp doh looks like I reversed my operators sorry about that